# How to use GPU with tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm running in a virtual environment.

So basically I have installed tensor flow, and when I run `import tensorflow as tf` the output I get is.

```
2021-08-11 17:42:31.395050: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
2021-08-11 17:42:31.395365: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
```

I have tried to install `CUDA` and `tf-nightly-gpu` like some oslutions have suggested but this hasn't fixed the problem.

current package list

```
Package                 Version
----------------------- -------------------
absl-py                 0.13.0
astunparse              1.6.3
cachetools              4.2.2
certifi                 2021.5.30
charset-normalizer      2.0.4
click                   8.0.1
colorama                0.4.4
cuda                    0.0.1
filelock                3.0.12
flatbuffers             1.12
gast                    0.4.0
gensim                  4.0.1
google-auth             1.34.0
google-auth-oauthlib    0.4.5
google-pasta            0.2.0
grpcio                  1.39.0
h5py                    3.1.0
huggingface-hub         0.0.12
idna                    3.2
joblib                  1.0.1
keras-nightly           2.7.0.dev2021081100
Keras-Preprocessing     1.1.2
libclang                11.1.0
Markdown                3.3.4
nltk                    3.6.2
numpy                   1.19.5
oauthlib                3.1.1
opt-einsum              3.3.0
packaging               21.0
Pillow                  8.3.1
pip                     21.2.3
protobuf                3.17.3
pyasn1                  0.4.8
pyasn1-modules          0.2.8
pyparsing               2.4.7
PyYAML                  5.4.1
regex                   2021.8.3
requests                2.26.0
requests-oauthlib       1.3.0
rsa                     4.7.2
sacremoses              0.0.45
scikit-learn            0.24.2
scipy                   1.7.1
sentence-transformers   2.0.0
sentencepiece           0.1.96
setuptools              57.4.0
six                     1.15.0
smart-open              5.1.0
tb-nightly              2.6.0a20210806
tensorboard             2.6.0
tensorboard-data-server 0.6.1
tensorboard-plugin-wit  1.8.0
tensorflow              2.5.1
tensorflow-estimator    2.5.0
tensorflow-hub          0.12.0
termcolor               1.1.0
tf-estimator-nightly    2.7.0.dev2021081101
threadpoolctl           2.2.0
tokenizers              0.10.3
torch                   1.9.0
torchvision             0.10.0
tqdm                    4.62.0
transformers            4.9.2
typing                  3.7.4.3
typing-extensions       3.7.4.3
urllib3                 1.26.6
Werkzeug                2.0.1
wheel                   0.37.0
wrapt                   1.12.1
```

How do I set up the GPU to make tensorflow use the GPU. I understand that it says you can enable GPU use, but there is no explanation how or where to first go.

Thanks

Comment: what GPU do you have?

Comment: see if this helps you https://youtu.be/StH5YNrY0mE

Comment: @bb1950328 nVIDIA

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you use Windows (due to the Error message)

You have to install NVIDIA CUDA - tensorflow 2.5.x uses 11.2 (see [version Table](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu))
also, i would recommend installing CUDNN 8.x too, since some layers (for instance LSTM) will use it

Check these guides:

[Tensorflow 2 installation guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#windows_setup)

[CUDA Download link](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads)

[CUDNN download link](https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn)

[Tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/installing-tensorflow-with-cuda-cudnn-and-gpu-support-on-windows-10-60693e46e781) - a detailed tutorial for an older CUDA version, but if you use the newer CUDA/CUDNN versions, the worflow is basically the same